# unix bash scripting what does [-a ] mean?

Tags: bash

Could someone explain how I am supposed to read/understand this piece of code. it's a question in a self test. (what does the `-a` stand for?)

```
[3 -a 5];
echo $?;
```

answers

```
0, 1, 5, 7, 8
```

Comment: `man bash` slash, `test expr` enter

Comment: `man bash | awk '/test expr/{f=2}f&&f--' RS=`

Comment: The correct answer is 127, unless an executable file `[3` is in path.

Answer (score 0):

See `man test`:

```
man test | grep -A2 -- -a
       EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
              both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true
```

The code is wrong however as there should be a space between `[` and `3`:

```
[ 3 -a 5 ]; echo "$?"
```